# Maintain history throughout project with single method

Tags: c#, sql-server, filter, triggers, database-trigger

I want to update history from one code through out project.
I have hierarchy of 2 layers consider top and bottom,
with 5 top(consider section) and each top section have 5 bottom(Sub section)
also 5 history tables for each top section. when I will update bottom(Sub section(s)) I am entering that data into history table(Section history table).

so I had written 25 different methods and 25 different procedures.

but I want something like instead of this so much of code only one automatic method/filter should update my particular top level history tables whenever I will  make changes in bottom sub sections

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.